# how to post data to server using angularJS, web api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, asp.net-web-api

i am new to angularJS and trying to figure out, how to post data to my server, problem is that my post to server is successful and it create new record but all is empty(null).

Thanks for any advice

JS:

```
    $scope.addChannel = function () {
    var channels = [];
    //var newChannel = {
    //    Name: $scope.Name
    //};
    //clearing error message
    $scope.errorMessage = "";

    $http.post("api/Channel/channels", newChannel)
        .success(function (newChannel) {
            //on success
            $scope.channels.push({ "Name": $scope.Name });
            console.log("data added");
           // newChannel.push(response.data);
            newChannel = {};
        }, function () {
            //on failure
            $scope.errorMessage = "Failed to save data";
        })
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ChannelController">
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
    <form novalidate name="newUser"ng-submit="addChannel()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Channel</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Name" name="Name" ng-model="newChannel.Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <a ng-href="/Dashboard#/channels">Return to dashboard</a>
</div>
<div class="has-error" ng-show="errorMessage">
    {{errorMessage}}
</div>
```

Channel Controller

```
        [HttpPost("channels")]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Create(Channel channel)
    {
        await _channelRepository.CreateChannel(channel);
    }
```

Repository

```
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task CreateChannel(Channel channel)
    {
        _context.Channel.Add(channel);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Please post the webapi method too

Comment: What is `newChannel` passed to $http.post ? Your data are in `$scope.newChannel.Name`.

Comment: Check the success callback signature: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Also, note that the `success`/`error` methods have been deprecated, it's recommended to use the `then`/`catch` promise methods instead.

Comment: updated question, with newChannel i mean that i will store into that object my channel name and then i post it into my property names channels but i definitely missing something which causing my problem, but not sure what is that

Comment: You need to call `$http.post("api/Channel/channels", $scope.newChannel)`

Comment: i tried that also with  $scope.newChannel, but still not working

Comment: Do you know if your server is correctly handling json parameters ? It may not be able to map the object to your Channel (server side).

Comment: i am sure it does, since i am able to get all stored data without any problem which i inserted directly to my db before

Comment: so i tried to use postman to send post request to my server and it successfully saved everything using content-type: application/json, but when i set up this content type in my js file using $httpProvider, still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you name properties correctly in object that you send to server, property names are case sensitive. Looks like you have in js

```
var customer = {name: 'foo', lastName: 'bar'};
```

and on server you try to deserialize your JSON to this entity

```
class Customer {
  public Name {get;set;} //note prop names are capitalized
  public LastName {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: property names should be correct, i use every model property with capital first letter